# sql.NullInt64 to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, rest, go

I have a database schema where Age is **optional**. But when in Go, via my RestFUL interface, I output the data as JSON, I get a very ugly response like `{"ID":1,"Name":"John","age":{"Int64":0,"Valid":false}}`
 for age. I expected a null value to be omitted. What am I missing?

```
// CREATE TABLE users (
//        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
//        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
//        age INT
// );

// Age is optional

type user struct {
    ID   int           `db:"id"`
    Name string        `db:"name"`
    Age  sql.NullInt64 `db:"age" json:"age,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    u := user{ID: 1, Name: "John"}
    j, _ := json.Marshal(u)
    fmt.Printf("%s", j)
}

// Expected: {"ID":1,"Name":"John"} since age is NULL/empty
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PS1-4Gw9h5u

Answer (score 3):

`sql.NullInt64` exists because SQL's `null` cannot be represented as Go's `int`. It's a third state that cannot be represented by any `int` value.

One solution to that would be to represent such SQL values as `*int`, but that would require an allocation for cases where the value is not `null` in the database, and allocations are bad for performance.

Designers of SQL package came up with `NullInt64` solution that encodes the third state of null as an additional `Valid` boolean. It's not a good solution but it's the best we can get.

I'm not sure if it's possible to write JSON marshaller for `NullInt64` that would work as you expect.

There's still the "third state" problem when marshalling to JSON. With `,omitempty` a `0` int would also be omitted so how can you tell 0 from "not exists"/null?

Either way they didn't write custom marshaller for `NullInt64` so it just encodes as the struct that it is.

You can create an alias type for `NullInt64`, write a JSON marshaller to encode the way you want to JSON (you need an alias because you can't add methods to types from other packages). You would also need to cast between your `NullInt64` and `sql.NullInt64`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom type for null int64.
This type works as you expected.

Usage example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "database/sql/driver" 
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type user struct {
    ID   int             `db:"id"`
    Name string          `db:"name"`
    // pointer needed to omitempty work, otherwise output will be "age": null
    Age  *NullInt64 `db:"age" json:"age,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    u := user{ID: 1, Name: "John"}
    j, _ := json.Marshal(u)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", j)
}

//    Output:
//        {"ID":1,"Name":"John"}

type NullInt64 struct {
    Val     int64
    IsValid bool
}

func NewNullInt64(val interface{}) NullInt64 {
    ni := NullInt64{}
    ni.Set(val)
    return ni
}

func (ni *NullInt64) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    ni.Val, ni.IsValid = value.(int64)
    return nil
}

func (ni NullInt64) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if !ni.IsValid {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return ni.Val, nil
}

func (ni *NullInt64) Set(val interface{}) {
    ni.Val, ni.IsValid = val.(int64)
}

func (ni NullInt64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !ni.IsValid {
        return []byte(`null`), nil
    }

    return []byte(strconv.FormatInt(ni.Val, 10)), nil
}

func (ni *NullInt64) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if data == nil || string(data) == `null` {
        ni.IsValid = false
        return nil
    }

    val, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(data), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        ni.IsValid = false
        return err
    }

    ni.Val = val
    ni.IsValid = true

    return nil
}

func (ni NullInt64) String() string {
    if !ni.IsValid {
        return `<nil>`
    }

    return strconv.FormatInt(ni.Val, 10)
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just work with `sql.NullInt64` and avoid defining your own `NullInt64`? is it because it's the only way to do a custom JSON marshaller?

Comment: yes, json.Marshaler, fmt.Stringer, also I need a NullTime, so I decided to write all I need in one place :)